# Github: How to list organization members who have created Private Access Tokens?

Tags: github, github-api

Other than emailing everyone and asking them (and hoping they respond), how do I get a list of which of my organization's members have created personal access tokens?

My immediate use for this is a rather sad one: Github only supports API tokens with write access bound to users. In years past, some people have created automatic processes using their private access token; this happens in early-stage startups. Occasionally we have the problem of people leaving under suboptimal conditions, so to speak, and of course when their credentials get revoked, something breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe GitHub provides this information, so you'll have to email and ask.

However, because GitHub is deprecating password authentication for Git, *almost every user* will have a PAT.  Even before this, they were required for everyone with 2FA using HTTPS, and because many organizations require 2FA, that practically means everyone will have them unless they're using SSH exclusively.  So the answer this question doesn't really tell you anything related to your intended goal, since the likely answer is “everyone.”

What I would do in this case is create a bot or machine account with its own email address tied to your company's domain, and then rotate tokens individually using that account.  If you need to keep track of which ones are rotated and which aren't, hash the ones you've issued with the machine account with SHA-256 and store them in a list.  If the hashed token is in the list, then it's been rotated; otherwise, it hasn't.

Comment: We've long since banned https+password access in favor of ssh, but that's not really relevant to PAT, which is how a service would authenticate to github (I guess expecting them to support client-side tls authentication is too much). We already have a "service" user for current needs, what I'm dealing with is legacy PATs from before I started running things with an iron fist :)

Comment: PATs can be used for both API access and Git access.

Comment: My last-ditch workaround is: I iterate over all my users (except for me!), remove them from the organization, then invite them back.